# How to add java.util.Scanner class to read two-dimensional array of float entries input?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question about using java.util.Scanner class to read two-dimensional array of float entries input, I've tried to find on internet, but still can't work. The code show me errors. Anyone can check for me which part I get wrong? Below is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class CloneTwoDarray {
  public static float[][] clone(float[][] a) throws Exception {
  float b[][] = new float[a.length][a[0].length];

  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
     b[i][j] = a[i][j];
     }
     }
       return b;
         }
   public static void main(String args[]) {


       float[][] a = new float[][];


       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.println("Type nine float numbers two-dimensional array of similar type and size with line breaks, end by \"-1\":");
       String append = "";
         while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         String input = sc.nextLine();
             if ("-1".equals(input)) {
    break;
          }
              lines.add(input);
         }

            sc.close();



            System.out.println("\n\nThe result is:\n");
           try {
             float b[][] = clone(a);
           for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
          System.out.print(b[i][j] + " ");
              }
            System.out.println();
            }
           } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Error!!!");
     }   
               }
       }
```

The output error show me like below:

```
        C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 
           Cancelled by user.
           BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Actually I want the output show me like below:

```
run:
Type nine float numbers two-dimensional array of similar type and size with line breaks, end by"-1":
1.513
2.321
3.421 
4.213
5.432 
6.123 
7.214
8.213 
9.213 
-1


The result is:

1.513 2.321 3.421 
4.213 5.432 6.123 
7.214 8.213 9.213 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 second)
```

Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: `float[][] a = new float[][];` is not valid

Comment: You can either prompt the use for the size of the array or use a `List`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for you comment. Can you edit my code to show me the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your goal is. Also, you define a method `CloneTwoDarray` that is never used. Your line formatting needs to be adjusted to be more readable.

As for the code itself, `lines.add(input)` accesses an object, `lines`, that was never defined.

`float[][] a= new float[5][5];` is an example of declaring a two dimensional array with 5 `rows` and 5 `columns`. `float[][] a = new float[][]`is not a correct declaration.

Your stack trace does not provide enough information.

Java's garbage collection will generally take care of closing `Scanner` for you, you do not need to utilize `sc.close()` in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Can you edit my code to show me the correct way?